# Handling failed message with JSQMessageViewController

Tags: ios, swift2, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I have successfully implemented sending and receiving message with JSQMessageViewController. However, I would like to add the visual effect on each message to distinguish whether the message has been successfully sent, or failed due to network issues as in the following image.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea on how should I implement this feature? I looked at the library for outgoingMessagesBubbleImageWithColor, it doesn't have anything like this build in.

Comment: you should implement it ,because JSQMessageViewController hasn't this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the Cell bottom label the reference documentation is here http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/JSQMessagesViewController/7.2.0/Classes/JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell.html#//api/name/cellBottomLabel

Returns the label that is pinned to the bottom of the cell. This label is most commonly used to display message delivery status.